# How to make a div content hidden when it's overflow to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

I have this above image, I need to achieve an effect with CSS and JavaScript; on my page I allow users to add up to 12 images to their account, and all the images will be displayed in the div below.

If a user has less than 5 photos the div with red border will be hidden, and when a user has more than 5 photos the div with red border will display with the 2 arrows – one on the left and the other on the right side – and clicking the right arrow the photos will move left until it get to the last photo.

How can I achieve this with CSS and JavaScript? I tried to use overflow hidden for the div, but what I got wasn't what I needed.

Any help on this from any one?

My HTML and CSS is below:

```css
.mycarousel-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 650px;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}
#carousel_control_left {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#carousel_control_right {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.mycarousel {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 4px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div><small class="text-muted">This listing has 6 photos. Add up to 6 more for free.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="mycarousel-container" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;">
      <span id="carousel_control_left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></span>
      <span id="carousel_control_right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
      <div class="mycarousel">
        <img src="1465929515_Money.png" class="img img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="mycarousel">
        <img src="1465929515_Money.png" class="img img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="mycarousel">
        <img src="1465929515_Money.png" class="img img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="mycarousel">
        <img src="1465929515_Money.png" class="img img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="mycarousel">
        <img src="1465929515_Money.png" class="img img-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/s7c23vLq/)

Comment: please add a jsfiddle.

Comment: You forgot to post your JavaScript/jQuery that you tried.

Comment: @DavidThomas i have to try had no idea how to make this work, thank

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest **not** adding those two arrows and letting the browser do the work for you?

Just set `overflow-x: auto` on the containing div.  This will enable scrolling, so all the native capability (such as two-finger swiping) will work in the way that the user expects it for the platform they're on.  This is a much better solution than reinventing UI components in ways that users don't expect.